# WMI win32_groupuser slow performance in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

Not sure if this is me. I wrote a script to check for the existence of a domain group in Local Administrators on remote servers. Due to the existence of over 20 domains in my company--many of them isolated from each other--I'm not sure if this would work using AD cmdlets. Instead, I thought I'd query each server's WMI directly, a solution that usually works for me.

Not in this case. Here's the meat of my script:

```
$admin = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser –computername $server | Where-Object $_.PartComponent -match $domaingroup} | Measure-Object
```

If the group is present, then $admin has a positive count and I can report on that. Otherwise the count is 0 and that's okay too.

But today, I was asked to check for the existence of the group on 200 servers, and my script failed me. It was dog slow. It would take five to ten *minutes* to get the result from each server. I can log onto a server and visually check for the group faster than that.

Is this one of those WMI groups that, I don't know, rebuilds an entire database every time it's touched, or something weird? Any suggestions for a faster script?

Comment: This [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/08/weekend-scripter-who-are-the-administrators.aspx) might shed some light on the performance problems.

Comment: This is apparently a problem with this particular WMI interface; the backend contacts the domain controller and requests a ton of objects one at a time. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302857) and [here](http://setspn.blogspot.com/2014/09/active-directory-lsassexe-high-cpu-usage.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use an ADSI query, something like:

```
$Results = ForEach($Server in (Get-Content .\ServerList.txt)){
    $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Server/Administrators"
    [PSCustomObject]@{'Server'=$Server
    'Group Found' = [boolean](@($group.Invoke("Members")) |
        foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}|
        Where{ $_ -match $domaingroup}| Measure-Object)
    }
}
```

That should leave you with an array of server names and True/False if the AD group was found in the local administrators group.

Comment: The problem there, of course, is that the group might not be named 'Administrators'.

Comment: Well, that's certainly faster. However, it's reporting back True even on servers where I've checked the group doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$computerName = "."
$wmiEnumOpts = new-object System.Management.EnumerationOptions
$wmiEnumOpts.BlockSize = 20
$argList = @{
  "Class" = "Win32_Group"
  "ComputerName" = $computerName
  "Filter" = "LocalAccount=TRUE AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'"
}
get-wmiobject @argList | foreach-object {
  $_.GetRelated("Win32_Account","Win32_GroupUser","","",
  "PartComponent","GroupComponent",$FALSE,$wmiEnumOpts)
}
```

More detail is in a blog post I wrote a while ago:

[Weekend Scripter: Who are the Administrators?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/08/weekend-scripter-who-are-the-administrators.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I finally went a different route:

```
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Server/$LocalGroupName"
$members = @($group.Invoke("Members"))
foreach ($member in $members) {
$MemberName = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
if ($MemberName -eq $DomainGroupName) {
$GroupFound++ }}
```

So if $GroupFound ends up greater than 0, report a successful find. Otherwise, reset it to 0 and start over on the next server in my list. Each server reports back in less than 10 seconds or so, about a 25:1 improvement.

Very close to TheMadTechnician's solution, so thanks for that.